# I can't get the sound to actually play

Tags: python, audio

So this is python. And I need help adding sound. I'm using CMU CS academy. And this is my current code-

`music = Sound('https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=HCslYhHcWkU&list=RDAMVMHCslYhHcWkU')`

```
def onKeyPress(key): if (key == 'p'): 
     if (pausedLabel.value == 'Paused...'): 
         pausedLabel.value = 'Playing!' 
          music.play(loop=True)

     else: 
          pausedLabel.value = 'Paused...' 
           music.pause()
```

Comment: Edit:   I forgot what the def for music is . music = Sound('https://music.youtube.com/watch?v=HCslYhHcWkU&list=RDAMVMHCslYhHcWkU')